# Mouse cursor corrupted by Adobe Indesign

Tags: windows-7, mouse, adobe-indesign

When using Adobe InDesign on Windows 7, the mouse cursor becomes corrupted after performing functions where the software displays a custom cursor. This only seems to happen on the display driven by the on-motherboard Intel graphics hardware (the driver reads as Intel GMA 4500).

Running the Magnifier program included with Window 7 seems to fix the problem when it is running but the corrupted cursor returns when I close Magnifier.

I've tried to set the cursors to another set and then back again in the control panel but that hasn't worked.

What I'm hoping for is a simple script which would refresh the mouse cursors.

Thoughts?

Comment: My initial thought is that you should ask this on SuperUser.

Comment: My initial thought is that you should report this as a bug to Adobe.

Comment: You already refreshed the curser, somehow you need to refresh the whole curser buffer that is the hardware acceleration for the curser stuff. before win 7 a person could pull cursers out of hardware acceleration and solve such problems using DXdiag. Agreeing with WesleyDavid it is the program doing different things, and the video driver/hardware not working with it correct. they will cross blame eachother :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this issue and updated my display adapter driver (Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset). Driver update should fix this issue.

Comment: I updated my Intel driver this morning and it fixed the issue.